# Unity Shoot Ball From POV of Camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, transform

I know this has been asked a few times but I believe my question can be solved without too much trouble (hopefully!) and is somewhat unique.  I'm writing a mini-golf script that shoots the ball, intended to shoot away from the POV of the camera.  I can't get it to do so however.  I'm sure it has something to do with camera.transform but not sure.  I'm a total noob to coding in Unity.  I just need a simple, straightforward way to get this dang golf ball to travel in a straight line in whatever direction the camera is facing.  Please help!

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HitBall2 : MonoBehaviour
{

    Rigidbody rigidBody;
    bool StartedShot;
    Vector3 shotStart;
    Vector3 shotEnd;
    Vector3 direction;
    public float distance;
    public float forceAdjust = 0.05f;

    void Start()
    {

        rigidBody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        StartedShot = false;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            this.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
            StartedShot = false;
        }

        // Starting shot
        if (!StartedShot && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            StartedShot = true;
            shotStart = Input.mousePosition;
        }

        // Ending shot
        if (StartedShot && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            shotEnd = Input.mousePosition;
            direction =  Camera.main.transform.forward - shotEnd;
            float distance = direction.magnitude;
            StartedShot = false;

            Vector3 shootDirection = new Vector3(direction.x, 0.0f, direction.y);

            rigidBody.AddForce(shootDirection * rigidBody.mass * forceAdjust, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Camera.main.transform.forward?

Comment: `direction =  Camera.main.transform.forward;` instead of `direction =  Camera.main.transform.forward - shotEnd;`

Comment: What is the problem? Does the ball shoot at all? Does it shoot backwards?

Comment: @CaTs, it shoots perpendicular to the camera toward the left (on the x axis), it doesn't shoot away from the camera.

Comment: I've tried Camera.main.transform.forward but it doesn't work the way I'd hoped.  I think my problem might be with "Vector3 shootDirection = new Vector3(direction.x...).  I'm clipping this code from someone else (thanks!) but not experienced enough to edit it the way I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentined in comments above, to shoot forward just use cameras transform.forward

Answer (score 0):

Okay I changed the script as follows and the ball now travels away from the camera.  There's a little problem with the velocity of the ball and the little y-axis jump it does but I'm sure it's easily figured out.

changed " Vector3 shootDirection = new Vector3(direction.x, 0.0f, direction.y);"

to   Vector3 shootDirection = Camera.main.transform.forward;

Thanks everyone!